# How to remove table top padding with QuickDialog library in IOS 7?

Tags: ios, quickdialog

I am using **QuickDialog library** in my IOS project. But it has a problem with table appearance:

[image]

The height of headerView in first table section is 10. But the top padding is much more than 10!

The table frame is right(fullscreen), and quickDialogTableView.contentInsets.top is also right(==64). But what the additional top space is? How to hack the library code to fix the problem?

**Notice: it only happens when root.grouped == YES.**

Comment: just try to remove height of first section of headerView ... and now check it.

Comment: Note: I don't have time to properly go into this right now, but if it's the same issue I'd been having, it's related to the fact that iOS7 grouped tableviews have overlarge section spacing.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGRect frame = self.quickDialogTableView.tableHeaderView.frame;
    frame.size.height = 5;
    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    self.quickDialogTableView.tableHeaderView = headerView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually based on Sebastian answer this works, but is kind of hackie...

```
self.quickDialogTableView.tableHeaderView = 
             [UIView.alloc initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0.1)];
```